# unable to install LAN Messenger 1.2.32 ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: kubuntu, lan

I tried to install [LAN Messenger 1.2.32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lanmsngr/files/1.2.32/lmc_1.2.32_i386.deb/download) on my Kubuntu 14.04.3.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i lmc_1.2.32_i386.deb
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then I tried to run `./lmc` and I got:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libsqlite3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After installing `libsqlite3-0`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsqlite3-0:i386
```

It claimed for libgtk and I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0:i386
```

Now it says:

```
This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
/usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869830/genymotion-error-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) post:

> sudo  apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386

Answer (score 2):

**Here is some solutions I collected from others  when I encounter the similar question**:

```
zhangtao@Elementary-OS:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i lmc_1.2.32_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package lmc.
(Reading database ... 198043 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack lmc_1.2.32_i386.deb ...
Unpacking lmc (1.2.32) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lmc:
lmc depends on libaudio2; however:
Package libaudio2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package lmc (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1+elementary2~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lmc
zhangtao@Elementary-OS:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install -f
......
......
......
zhangtao@Elementary-OS:~/Downloads$ lmc
This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
/usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
zhangtao@Elementary-OS:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libqtcore4:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqtgui4:i386

zhangtao@zhangtao-lfs:~/Downloads$ lmc
This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
/usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlite3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
zhangtao@zhangtao-lfs:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libsqlite3-0:i386

zhangtao@zhangtao-lfs:~/Downloads$ lmc
This is not a Canonical "designed" product.
/usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
zhangtao@zhangtao-lfs:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
```